# How can I run python scripts on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, python

I'm new to Windows 7 and with my Python installation. When I specify `script.py` in `cmd.exe` and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd>, instead of executing the python file, I am given an error message (sth like "not a command").

How do I tell Windows to run the Python interpreter when specifying or double-clicking a Python script?

Answer (score 6):

Associate the `.py` extension with the `python.exe` interpreter executable. Normally the installer does this for you.

Comment: Thanks, and here's how to:
http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html

Comment: I'd rather suggest to associate the .py extension with the pythonw.exe by default, to anticipate the question "It works now, but I don't want to see that cmd window."